# why pthread_create function takes thread function name as a parameter rather than calling it?

Tags: c

In my program, a call to `pthread_create` looks like:

```
res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, thread_fn, (void*)n);
```

My question is, why can't we make it:

```
res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, thread_fn( (void*)n) );
```

since this will reduce the number of parameters in `pthread_create` and also looks logical, as for a function I have learnt only 3 things: declaration, definition and  calling.

Passing the function name as a parameter and adding to that passing its argument as a separate parameter is a thing I don't understand.

If there is any logic behind this format, kindly explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most obvious argument would be that you cannot call `thread_fn` "as an argument" because then it would need to run to completion *before* `pthread_create` could be called -- that is, you would run the code destined for the new thread in the current thread.

Another way of looking at things is that creating a thread of execution necessarily taps into OS (kernel) code; the OS needs to set up its internal bookkeeping structures before the new thread becomes effectively usable. A kernel call such as caused by `pthread_create` needs to know the memory address of the code to be executed in a thread so that it can transfer control to that location after setting everything up, and passing the *address* of a function (as opposed to its return value) is done with the first syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, **thread_fn( (void*)n)** );

Keep in mind that the part in bold is a function call. The semantics of the C language call for execution of that function call, and then substituting its return value in it's place. So, this syntax, is equivalent to the following sequence of things.

1. temp = thread_fn( (void*)n) // function call
2. res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, temp)

This is obviously not what you want. What you want is for the function pthread_create to first create a separate thread of execution, which executes the function call thread_fn with the argument that you specified.

Following is what pthread_create needs to do.

1. Create a new thread execution context.
2. Setup the call context for thread_fn i.e. setup stack and arguments etc.
3. Arrange for thread_fn to be entered.

Because the function thread_fn gets executed in a deferred fashion, the only way to do it is to set aside the function entry point and its arguments, and then arrange for it be executed. Which is why these are passed in as arguments to pthread_create.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function as a parameter to a function call, what actually happens is that the function is called and the `return value` is placed on the stack to pass to the function you are calling.

```
strthings(getStr1(), strlen(getStr1()), getStr2(), strlen(getStr2()));
```

translates to (the order may vary depending on compiler/cpu)

```
auto t1 = getStr2();   // probably not exact order
auto t2 = strlen(t1);
auto t3 = getStr1();
auto t4 = strlen(t3);
strthings(t3, t4, t1, t2);
```

So - your piece of code:

```
*res = pthread_create   (&a_thread , NULL , thread_fn( (void*)n) )
```

would translate to

```
// run the thread function and get the return value.
auto t1 = thread_fn((void*n));
*res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, t1);
```

We'd be running the thread_fn in OUR thread context and then passing it's return value. It sounds like you were expecting functions-as-parameters to be passed to the called function and interpreted inline?

Why does passing the function and the argument work?

--- EDIT: Explanation of why passing a function and parameter separately works.

In C, function names are actually pointer variables. The type of the pointer depends on the 'fingerprint' of the function.

```
int strncmp(const char* left, const char* right, int maxlen);
```

is actually

```
int (*strncmp)(const char*, const char*, int);
```

that is, strncmp is a pointer to a function returning a void and taking three arguments of the specified types.

This forms a contract, so that when you write

```
int n = strncmp(a, b, 3);
```

it knows to do something in [presudo] assembly like:

```
push a
push b
push 3
call 0x783af83  // strncmp
mov  return -> n
pop  12
```

So - now that you know functions are actually pointers (to code) you can see how it is possible to pass them, so that you can do things like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int func1() { return 1; }
int func2() { return 22; }

int flip(int useFirst, int (*first)(), int (*second)()) {
    return (useFirst) ? first() : second();
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int useFirst = rand() % 2;
    int result = flip(useFirst, func1, func2);
    printf("use first is %u. return value was %u.\n", useFirst, result);
}
```